# No edit action buttons in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, google-chrome

In Chrome today (and perhaps earlier) when I attempt to add an answer to a StackOverflow question, I find no row of buttons above the entry box and so cannot easily add links or font styles.  If I log in with IE, no problem.  [Windows 7/64]

Comment: I cannot reproduce that here. Did you clear your cache and reload the page? Some javascript probably failed to load.

Comment: Can't reproduce it either, tried logging in unprimed from a VM as well.

Comment: Most likely cache issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the evidence points to this having been a cache issue.  It is not possible to confirm this because the problem no longer occurs.

Please do not again delete my answer to my own (implied) question.  The fact that I have accepted the strong probability that it was a cache issue may be of value to others who research a similar problem.